# Error while printing invoice

Tags: magento-1.7, error, invoice, print

I've got a standard Magento 1.8.0.0 installation on Windows 7
using the BitNami Magento installation for XAMPP.

When I open the *Sales -> Invoices* screen and click on an
invoice and then click on the orange Print button in the
upper right hand corner of the screen I get the following
error message inside the web browser:

> Fatal error: Declaration of
>   Zend_Pdf_FileParserDataSource_File::__construct() must be compatible
>   with Zend_Pdf_FileParserDataSource::__construct() in
>   C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\lib\Zend\Pdf\FileParserDataSource\File.php
>   on line 41

Anyone know why I am getting this and how to fix this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Magento in versions **before CE 1.9 / EE 1.14** is not compatible with PHP 5.4 out of the box, which causes this error.

Anyways, there is [an official patch for this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/php5.4_patch.html).

Comment: Alan Storm wrote a long article about the patch. And you want to use this patch, because it fixes more "no backwards compatibility" issues http://alanstorm.com/anatomy_of_the_magento_php_54_patch

Comment: Tried this, but in my case I'm staying stuck with the same error.

Comment: Oke, got it working after `Run Compilations Process`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23820792/1643487

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: also not available for 1.5

Answer (score 29):

This an incompatibility issue between PHP Version 5.4.4 and zend Framwork .

Fixed it by change in this function  lib/Zend/Pdf/FileParserDataSource.php.

change

```
abstract public function __construct();
```

to

```
abstract public function __construct($filePath);
```

Comment: perfect and to the point !!!

Comment: It's working perfect man....Thank you for sharing!!!

Comment: SUPEE-2631 is the official patch to resolve this.  It also fixes compatibility issues in 3 other files.  The link is in the answer above, but I'll re-paste it here. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/php5.4_patch.html