# Can't generate PDF invoices or packing slips in Magento

Tags: error, invoice, pdf, zend-framework

I have a Magento issue. I have moved everything to a different server, and all seems to work fine - but I can not get the "print PDF invoice"  or "Packingslip" option in the order section to work. It just shows a blank page when I try. What could be the problem here?

Thanks!

Comment: try turning on logging and see if there is anything written into var/logs/system.log

Comment: your php version? look for this question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9721/error-while-printing-invoice/9730#9730

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for your responses. @DavidManners - I have logging turned on, and nothing is listed in system.log relating to this.

Comment: @Mufaddal - I had a look at that and tried changing the file in question, it did not work. Sometimes I'll just get a blank page, and sometimes it will say "There are no printable documents related to selected orders". Odd. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Compilation on?

Comment: @Mufaddal Hi - Compilation is not enabled.

Answer (score 2):

as user2694249 said correctly, the problem is a missing backwards compatibility of magento relative to php 5.3/4

The "bug" is already fixed in the newer Zend_Framework 1 versions, but magento has old versions shipped with it.

[The bug is fixed with a patch, magento offers](https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/magento-now-supports-php-54). A EE fix is accessable via your internal account area.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution to the problem described above:

Open up: /lib/Zend/Pdf/FileParserDataSource.php
and comment out:

```
//abstract public function __construct();
//abstract public function __destruct();
```

Taken from: http://www.pcwired.com/2013/09/my-magento-on-php-5-4-x-fixes

This is caused by a compatibility issue with PHP 5.4.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe just use the patch by magento? http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/magento-now-supports-php-54/

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt write it up as a complete answer :D