# Zend compatible error in magento admin

Tags: shipping, pdf, zend-framework

I am getting the following error when i was printing the shipment
Fatal error: Declaration of Zend_Pdf_FileParserDataSource_File::__construct() must be compatible with Zend_Pdf_FileParserDataSource::__construct()

I also tried the links for the answer as follows.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516620/magento-php-5-4-pdf-invoice-zend-error

But no solution , Pls help .

Comment: Are you using php 5.4 if so you should use the magento offical patch as mentioned http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/18268/158

Comment: what version of php are you using?

Comment: I am using php 5.4.29

Comment: Then I would suggest this is the issue mentioned in that answer. You should look into working with the patch provided by magento

Comment: Hi all , Thanks for the answer , I had downgrade the PHP version from 5.4 to 5.3 , And now its working fine . Thanks once again.